# $\int_{R}|f(x+t)-f(x)|dx\leq |t|^{1+\delta} \quad$ implys that $f=0$ almost everywhere.

Tags: lebesgue-integral, fourier-transform

### Qusetion

Suppose that $f\in L^1(R)$ , and there is a constant $\delta>0$,such that $\int_{R}|f(x+t)-f(x)|dx\leq |t|^{1+\delta}$ for all t , then $f=0$ almost everywhere.

---

### Attempt

I think the following lemma is useful.

Lemma:If $f\in L^1(R)$ , let  $\hat{f}(\lambda)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{-ix\lambda}dx$ , if$\hat{f} \equiv 0 $ ,then $f=0$ almost everywhere.

Notice that , for $\lambda \neq 0$ , we can show that :
$$\hat{f}(\lambda)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{-ix\lambda}dx=-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x+\frac{\pi}{\lambda})e^{-ix\lambda}dx$$
$$|\hat{f}(\lambda)|\leq\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(x+\frac{\pi}{\lambda})-f(x)|dx\leq \frac{1}{2}|\frac{\pi}{\lambda}|^{1+\delta}$$
Then $\hat{f} \in L^1（R)$. I believe that we can show that $\hat{f} \equiv 0 $ ,but  I have no idea to figure it out.

Can anyone give me some hint？Thank you.

---

Here's [an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3328695/if-l1-average-of-f-is-smaller-than-t2-then-f-0-a-e/3328718#3328718)!

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3328718/624428